# Amazon AWS Video Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am doing an app using Ionic where I need to allow the user to upload videos and eventually stream them. I want to use AWS to do that. Which AWS API should I use to do that? Should I use S3? How? I am little lost...

Comment: Your question is really too broad for this site. I would recommend uploading files to S3 and configuring CloudFront as a video streaming CDN in front of the S3 bucket. That's one of many ways you could solve this. I hope that helps you get started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

best option here is to:

1. Implement a web interface which allows users to "post" their files.
2. Files will be stored into an S3 Bucket
3. Serve the streaming of the files over AWS Cloudfront. Cloudfront offers video streaming built-in functionalities (here is a tutorial for this https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/)

All in all, the 3 steps are rather easy and straight forward.

For sure you need to spend some time on it. It does not come for free (in life nothing comes for free :) )

I hope this helps